# Where is ISubject?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I don't have ISubject, Subject class in my VS2012 with Net4.5.
Did they became obselete? Should I use only IObservable and IObserver? If not how can I get them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Rx 1.x, [`ISubject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229572%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) is defined in the `System.Reactive` assembly, so you'll need to add a reference to that.

In Rx 2.x, `ISubject` is defined in the `System.Reactive.Interfaces` assembly ([Rx-Interfaces NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/Rx-Interfaces/)) and `Subject<T>` is defined in the `System.Reactive.Linq` assembly ([Rx-Linq NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/Rx-Linq/)). You can just add a reference to Rx-Linq as it has a dependency on Rx-Interfaces.